# npm login error 301

Tags: npm, publish, http-status-code-301

Why am I getting error 301 Moved Permanently when running `npm adduser` / `npm login`?

```
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! Darwin 16.7.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/<my-user-name>/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.2/bin/node" "/Users/<my-user-name>/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.2/bin/npm" "adduser"
npm ERR! node v6.9.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9

npm ERR! Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
npm ERR! <html>
npm ERR! <head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
npm ERR! <body bgcolor="white">
npm ERR! <center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
npm ERR! <hr><center>nginx/1.8.1</center>
npm ERR! </body>
npm ERR! </html>
```

I am trying to publish a package into npm, and had no issues logging in yesterady (verified via `npm whoami`). I know that I have the correct npm username and password etc. because I can verify by logging into npm (https://www.npmjs.com/login). And as you can see, I am running node 6.9.2 and npm 3.10.9 (which should be latest).

Any ideas why this could be?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your client was pointing to a wrong/outdated registry URL?

For me it was pointing to http://registry.npmjs.org/ instead of https://registry.npmjs.org/ (see https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/registry):

```
$ npm adduser
npm ERR! code E301
npm ERR! Registry returned 301 for POST on 
http://registry.npmjs.org/-/v1/login
...
$ npm config get registry
http://registry.npmjs.org/
$ npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
$ npm adduser
Username: 
...
```